# Soft delete with cascade deletion doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, cascade, aspnetboilerplate, soft-delete

I'm using EF Core and SQLite in unit tests. Given the following 1-to-1 entities:

```
public class Entity1 : FullAuditedEntity<int>
{
    public Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Entity2 : FullAuditedEntity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }       

    [ForeignKey("Entity1Id")]
    public Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
    public int Entity1Id { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext` class has the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity1>().HasOne(t => t.Entity2)
                                  .WithOne(t1 => t1.Entity1)
                                  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    ...
}
```

I have a test method:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Should_Create_And_Then_Delete_Single_Entity1()
{
    var entity1Service = Resolve<Entity1Service>();
    var entity1Repo = Resolve<IRepository<Entity1>>();
    var entity2Repo = Resolve<IRepository<Entity2>>();
    var entity1 = new entity1 { Name = "ent1" };

    entity2Repo.Count().ShouldBe(0);

    // entity2 created also, see assert below
    var created = await entity1Service.CreateEntity1Async(entity1).ConfigureAwait(false);
    created.Id.ShouldBe(1);
    created.Name.ShouldBe("net1");

    entity1Repo.Count().ShouldBe(1);
    entity2Repo.Count().ShouldBe(1);

    var ent = await entity1Service.GetEntity1Async(created.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
    ent.ShouldNotBeNull();
    ent.Entity2.ShouldNotBeNull();

    await entity1Service.DeleteEntity1Async(ent.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);

    entity1Repo.Count().ShouldBe(0);
    entity2Repo.Count().ShouldBe(0);
}
```

The problem is that the last line of code, `"entity2Repo.Count().ShouldBe(0);"` assertion is broken, it is actually 1 instead of 0, `IsDeleted` (soft delete) is `false`, but I expect it to be `true`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cascade soft deletes yourself.
See the rationale in the closed PR [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#3559](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/3559).

You can do that by defining an [event handler](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EventBus-Domain-Events#DocHandleEvents):

```cs
public class Entity1DeletingCascader : IEventHandler<EntityDeletingEventData<Entity1>>, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IRepository<Entity2> _entity2Repository;

    public Entity1DeletingCascader(IRepository<Entity2> entity2Repository)
    {
        _entity2Repository = entity2Repository;
    }

    [UnitOfWork]
    public virtual void HandleEvent(EntityDeletingEventData<Entity1> eventData)
    {
        var entity1 = eventData.Entity;
        _entity2Repository.Delete(e2 => e2.Entity1Id == entity1.Id);
    }
}
```